# How to get value by key from unstructured json column in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-11

I have jsonb column with unstructured json. It can contain any combination of keys and arrays.

I need to find if the value of key "Grade" contains the specified string. I managed to do that in Postgres 12.1 using *jsonb_path_query_first*. Unfortunately I have no access to Postgres 12 in production and the highest I can go is the version 11.

I tried everything I could think of to solve this in Postgres 11, but nothing worked. Basically I need to translate this to work with Postgres 11:

```
select "Id" from (
  select (jsonb_path_query_first("Data", '$.**."Grade" ? (@ <> null)')) as grade, "Id" from "Product"
  where "GroupId" = '8435c76f-f7ab-44d7-b72f-b2a6f0465df5' or "GroupId" = '71010f76-fd97-4aa4-99d1-dadc3a5f9675'
) 
as test where grade is not null and grade::text like '%test%';
```

Example data:

```
{
"general": [{"Grade": "aaaaaaaaaa"}, {"DesignationAnsi": "xxxxxxxx"}],
"details": [{"Name": "bbb", "Unit": null, "Value": "cccc", "Description": "ddd"}, {"Name": "eee", "Unit": null, "Value": "fff", "Description": "ggg"}]
}
```

Note: Grade can be null, may not be present at all, and can be present at multiple places at once (any value is ok)

Comment: @McNets Example added.

Comment: Is this key always located inside the "general" array?

Comment: @McNets Not always, it can be anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Do you always have the `general` and `details` keys, or can they change as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they can change as well